# TimeInterval to NSDate

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I work with API and I need to convert NSInterval to date.

For example, I have `NSNumber model.complaintCreatedTime = 1480550400000`.I try this method, but it doesn't work:

```
 NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate  :[(NSString *)model.complaintCreatedTime doubleValue ]];
```

Mb API developers wrote the bad request to created API? 
 Pls, smbd help me!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are using the wrong API and your time stamp is in milliseconds

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: model.complaintCreatedTime.doubleValue / 1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

the unit  is second，not millisecond。maybe you should try [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1480550400]